# How can I create a YAML pipeline in Azure Devops for a Xamarin Forms Android library project that generates a nuget package

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-devops, xamarin.android, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I have a Xamarin Forms Android project configured to generate a nuget package when it is compiled from Visual Studio (will be used as a library), but in the Azure pipeline configuration something is not working in the "Generate Nuget package" task.

This is the configuration in the YAML file:

```
pool:
  vmimage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  outputDirectory: '$(build.binariesDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore Nuget packages
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.Droid.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '426fe2cd-0983-468f-b5bd-8073930ec94c'

- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  displayName: Build project
  inputs:
    projectFile: '**/*.Droid.csproj'
    outputDirectory: '$(outputDirectory)'
    createAppPackage: true
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildVersionOption: '16.0'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Generate Nuget package
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.Droid.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'off'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish Nuget
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: '426fe2cd-0983-468f-b5bd-8073930ec94c'
```

And this is the error that shows when I run the pipeline:

> D:\a\1\s....Droid.csproj(183,5): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.401\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.401\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Other pipelines that I have configured work fine and are generating the nuget packages, but they are just Xamarin Forms projects, they don't include Xamarin.Android references.

A YAML example of these projects:

```
pool:
  vmimage: 'windows-2019'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore Nuget packages
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '426fe2cd-0983-468f-b5bd-8073930ec94c'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build project
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Generate Nuget package
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'off'
    
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish Nuget
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: '426fe2cd-0983-468f-b5bd-8073930ec94c'
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by turning your android app into a nuget package? You should put your external code in a class library which you build & publish as a nuget. Your android app project should be built & published as an apk

Comment: I have several apps that are using this project as a library, so this is not the project that must generate the APK. I have an iOS project that will be used as library indeed, in the same way as this one for Android, and must not generate an IPA. Hope this is the correct approach.

Comment: Ah ok so it’s an android class library. I have not built this type of library using the xamarin android task. If I need to target platforms from my library I will use multi targeting to achieve it. You would then just call the msbuild task directly. [Here is an example](https://github.com/Axemasta/SuperWebView/blob/main/build/azure-pipelines.yml) repo of a multi targeted class library that is built via azure pipeline.

Comment: Thanks @Axemasta, I will take a look. I have changed a bit the question to better reflect the project is a Xamarin Forms Android library.

Comment: I suspect your issue is that the xamarin android runtime has not been installed prior to running the task. You can use [Boots](https://github.com/jonathanpeppers/boots) to achieve this, here is a complete yaml [example](https://github.com/Axemasta/SuperWebView/blob/main/build/steps/set-runtime.yml)